# How can I insert an External Javascript link in Javascript(for Example in VS-Code) as it is inserted in Codepen?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, codepen

In Codepen there is a function to add links to the Javascript section (e.g. for jQuery, or others). Now I want to recreate a project from Code-Pen with Visual Studio Code. But I don't know how to include these links in VS code (it doesn't work with  in HTML). Below is a more detailed picture of what I mean. Does anyone have a tip, thanks!

Picture-Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy3Df.png

Comment: use the HTML `link` tag inside the `head` tag

Comment: What do you mean, _“it doesn't work with in HTML”_? You are aware that you will have to use `script` elements to embed script resources, and `link` for stylesheets, yes?

Comment: @rioV8 He wanted to embed  `javascript`, not `css`. Also OP didn't mention he's working with html (even tho it's very likely)

Comment: @DadiBit same principle use `script` tag

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, of course, maybe my comment sounded harsh, but my point was just that maybe OP wanted pure `js` embedding/importing.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding the link to the cdn in a script tag on your HTML file

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) link to the

```
  <html>
            <head>
                <script
                       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
                       integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
                       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </head>
    <body>
....
....
....
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to add both links, can I do that, this way, with two <script>, and from where I know the integrity link, for example for: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/769286/jquery.waitforimages.min.js" ?

Comment: you don't need always to add integrity for exemple this is the cdn of react look : `<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>`
it dont contain any integrity